# Paste Special Transpose for multiple files

Tags: vba, excel

First, I begin with having a Master File. The Master File has names of 40 other workbooks.

I need to write a VBA code that works on this 40 workbooks (names defined in A1-A40 in the masterfile). This code should go to each workbook, open it, and copy the data in the first sheet of each workbook.

Thereafter, it will go back to the Master workbook and paste special in separate new sheets. For example, workbookA1's data goes into Sheet1 and workbookA2's data goes into Sheet2. However, I am having some trouble with it. The error says "PasteSpecial Method of Range Class" failed.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim thiswb As Workbook, datawb As Workbook
    Dim datafolder As String
    Dim cell As Range, datawblist As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set thiswb = ActiveWorkbook
    i = 2
    'Have the 40 file names in sheet2 of this workbook in cells A1:A40
    Set datawblist = Sheets("command").Range("A1:A4")
    datafolder = "C:\Users\bryan\Desktop\Y4S1\Money and Banking\Empirical\QuarterSheets\2012q1\" 'change this to your directory they're in
    For Each cell In datawblist
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=datafolder & cell & ".csv", ReadOnly:=True
        Set datawb = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets(1).Select 'change this to the sheet name you need to copy from
        Range("A1:XFD1048576").Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            thiswb.Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, _
                Transpose:=True
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
            datawb.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Loop
        datawb.Close savechanges:=False
        thiswb.Activate
        Sheets("command").Select
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1).Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you try to copy from `datawb` to `thiswb`, which you should use try to utilize them and avoid using `activeworkbook` such as `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`

Comment: when opening a workbook you can set datawb and workbook.open in one line i.e. `Set datawb = Workbooks.Open (Filename:=datafolder & cell & ".csv", ReadOnly:=True)`. thus void confusing activeworkbook to the master workbok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which removes the Selects and Activates, and restricts the copied range to the used range rather than every single cell. I think I've interpreted your scenario correctly, but shout if not.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim thiswb As Workbook, datawb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim datafolder As String
Dim cell As Range, datawblist As Range
Dim i As Long

Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
i = 2
'Have the 40 file names in sheet2 of this workbook in cells A1:A40
Set datawblist = thiswb.Sheets("command").Range("A1:A4")
datafolder = "C:\Users\bryan\Desktop\Y4S1\Money and Banking\Empirical\QuarterSheets\2012q1\" 'change this to your directory they're in

For Each cell In datawblist
    Set datawb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=datafolder & cell & ".csv", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = thiswb.Sheets.Add(After:=thiswb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    datawb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=True
    datawb.Close savechanges:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you asap

Comment: The transpose worked for 1 worksheet, but not for the rest. Any solution with regards to that?

Comment: (Paste transpose worked for only 1 worksheet), whereas for other worksheets it was the traditional copy and paste

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using F8 to see what is going on. Do you definitely have valid file names in cells A1 to A4 of the correct sheet?

Comment: Dear SJR, I was a fool. This was because some of the files I worked on had already been transposed previous. +1 Thanks so much for your help, you are a beautiful human being. I will bother you again if I have any questions, will run it for the entire FDIC dataset now.

Comment: My pleasure. If it has worked please could you accept this as an answer?